# Prevent running of computed properties (dependentobservable) in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to prevent syncer property while constructing, because I could send persistedObject to X class.

```
    function X(persistanceObject) {
        var self = this;

        self.xid = -1;
        self.syncer = ko.computed(function () {
            // if  object construction in progress then return 

            // persist properties....
        }, self);
        self.y = ko.observable(43);

        if (typeof persistanceObject !== 'undefined') {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(persistanceObject, {}, self.y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent a computed observable from evaluating immediately by using the `deferEvalaution` option.

It would look like:

```
self.syncer = ko.computed(function () {
            // if  object construction in progress then return 

            // persist properties....
}, self, { deferEvaluation: true });
```

Now it will not evaluate until its value is accessed.  If you are not binding this in your UI, then you would want to call it at least once (`self.syncer()`) after all of your properties are ready.